# how to know from where the command ran in linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Suppose i ran a command in unix like `ls` or `rm` and path variable is set as below

```
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:.:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:$COBDIR/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin
```

How can we know `ls` command ran from which path ? `ls` (just an example) may be there in `/sbin` as well `/usr/bin`

So i would like to know from where it ran ?

i cannot afford to search all directory and know in which all directory `ls` is lying. is there a direct way to search `ls` from where it ran?

Answer (score 6):

When you run an external command in bash, bash hashes that command to avoid having to do the path lookup twice. The `hash` command can tell you which command was run. If the command has not been run in the hash's lifetime, it will give an error.

```
$ hash -t ls
-bash: hash: ls: not found

$ ls foo
$ hash -t ls
/bin/ls
```

It's advantageous to know how `hash`, `which` and the `type` command differ.

- `hash` tells you what path/command *was* used/hashed. If your PATH or filesystem changes during `hash`'s lifetime, `hash` can tell you about commands that happened before that change.
- `which` is an external command that looks up a command in the `PATH` environment variable.
- `type` is a builtin command that looks up a command in the local `PATH` variable, which can be (but hardly ever is) different from what's in the environment.

See `help hash` in your bash to read more about how it works.

Comment: `type` is probably the best option in most cases because it will correctly identify shell builtins, functions, and other such things.

Comment: This worked and the concept also got clear. The problem was in my current directory a file was lying whose name was 'ls'. So actual ls command was not working.   With hash command i was able to know that it was picked from current directory. instead of /bin .

Answer (score 4):

Just use which to locate from where exactly it's going to be picked up from

```
$ which ls
  /bin/ls
```

It will list which path it picked up that executable from. So from above command, my ls command is in /bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers mentioning `which`, `type`, `hash` you could also use the [whereis(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whereis.1.html) command (if it is installed on your system).

<sup>`whereis` tells you the standard places where a command should be.</sup>

If your interactive shell is [zsh](http://zsh.org/), you could also use the `=ls` word e.g. `echo =ls` or `ls =ls` to find out which `ls` is refered by the shell.

And you might also alias `ls`, or have a shell function `ls` masquarading the `/bin/ls` executable, etc.... Of course, programs could start `/bin/ls` *without* forking a shell (e.g. with plain `fork`+`execve` ...)

Read also [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) & [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)

Comment: `whereis` is a particularly poor choice as it gives a superset of what could be run. Because whereis first "attempts to locate the desired program in the standard Linux places" and `/usr/lib` is one of those places and ought not be in PATH, there is fair probability that it will yield an utterly misleading result.